# Add a column in a specific position in a specific dataframe from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes, like this:

```
a<-as.data.frame(a)
b<-matrix(1,nrow = 10,ncol = 10)
b<-as.data.frame(b)
c<-matrix(1,nrow = 10,ncol = 10)
c<-as.data.frame(c)
my_data<-list(a,b,c)
```

And I would like to add a column in a specific position (before the last column) but only for a specific `data.frame` (the first one, `a`). This is why I am using `add_column` from `tibble` package.

```
install.packages("tibble")
library("tibble")
my_column<-rep("new",10)
a<-add_column(a,my_column,.before = "V10")
```

This perfectly works on the single `data.frame`, but in my case the `data.frames` are imported all together in R. Thus, I would like to do something like this:

```
my_data<-add_column(my_data[[a]],my_column,.before = "V10")
```

But it is not working, as I get this error:
`Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `my_data[[a]]` will not work.  `[[]]` works only on indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
my_data[[1]] <- add_column(my_data[[1]], my_column,.before = "V10")
```

If you want to name dataframes in `list`:

```r
names(my_data) <- c("a", "b", "c")
my_data$a <- add_column(my_data$a, my_column, .before = "V10")
```